# Specify values before auto generated primark keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, primary-key, auto-increment

I want to create table called entries with the following fields. entry_id, and entry. Making entry_id the primary key field with data type of int. but before the primary keys are being generated i want there to be a value of 000 for the primary key starts counting. for example 0001,0002 and so forth

Comment: Int data type will ignore any zeros on the left side of a value. If you want your values to look like `001`, `002` you will need to use a character data type (VARCHAR, NVARCHAR), having said this you better of with 1, 2, 3... Integer values. Better performance wise and easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

On the database your identity will have to be an integer without the padding. If you want padding, you will have to pad it with 0's either when pulling the values from the db or when displaying them in your UI.

Create a table with an identity:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
 id int IDENTITY(1,1),
 firstname varchar (20),
 middleinitial char(1),
 lastname varchar(30)
);
```

To reseed at 0 if you need to, you can execute:

DBCC CHECKIDENT ( ‘databasename.dbo.yourtable’,RESEED, 0)

Comment: can you phrase the whole code from scratch in creating a table?

Comment: Showed an example. You'll need to use your own field names and types obviously.

Comment: it seems you are not getting my point, what i mean is not about reseeding but about for example and id of 12 will starting of 000 before the 12 comes. making it 00012 when anothing inserting comes it will be 00013

Comment: @blay That is what the Identity keyword does in the create table statement. Also, I said before you cannot have the padding in the db, you'll need to pad it when pulling the values out of the db.